# Navigation Drawer - Chamar câmera através do Menu

Tags: android

Estou com um problema, pegue o Layout do Android Studio Navigation Drawer para fazer meu projeto, porém quando quero chamar a classe câmera da erro.

> Criei uma outra classe para a câmera, onde tenho verificação do
>   GPS e o local onde será armazenado a imagem.

```
public class Camera extends Principal 
 {
private AlertDialog alerta;
public static final int IMAGEM_INTERNA = 1313;
public void Tirafoto (View view) 
  {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
    getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final boolean GPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled
(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (GPSEnabled) {
    Intent camera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(camera, IMAGEM_INTERNA);
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertas = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertas.setTitle("Ligar GPS");
        alertas.setMessage("Para usar essa função você deve ativar seu GPS");
        alertas.setPositiveButton("Ativar GPS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        alertas.setNegativeButton("Não Ligar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
 Toast.makeText(Camera.this, "Camera disponivel somente com o 
 uso do GPS=" + arg1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alerta = alertas.create();
        alerta.show();
    }
}
```

}

E na Activity principal tenho

```
if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        Camera camera =  new Camera();
```

Não sei como continuar, pois testei de varias formas mas não consegui fazer funcionar.

Comment: Sei que pode ser apenas um "rascunho" ou sei la o que, mas indico a você que verifique alguns erros de ortografia em algumas palavras do seu code.

Comment: Sim, e apenas um rascunho antes de colocar no meu projeto correto, mas não entendi onde tem erros de ortografia.

Comment: Camera disponivel somente com o usu do GPS

Answer (score 0):

Simulei o seu projeto aqui e o erro que acontece é: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Não entendi o motivo da classe Camera extender da Activity Principal.
Porque você não chama o código diretamente no clique do item do NavigationDrawer:

```
if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
                getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        final boolean GPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled
                (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (GPSEnabled) {
            Intent camera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(camera, IMAGEM_INTERNA);
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertas = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertas.setTitle("Ligar GPS");
            alertas.setMessage("Para usar essa função você deve ativar seu GPS");
            alertas.setPositiveButton("Ativar GPS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            alertas.setNegativeButton("Não Ligar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Camera disponivel somente com o uso do GPS=" + arg1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            alerta = alertas.create();
            alerta.show();
        }
    }
```